# What is the correct way to get only display plugin for Administrator Only

Tags: wp-admin, admin

Currently I'm a little confused with the usage of `is_admin()` and `current_user_can( 'manage_options' )`

What is the right way for it?

At this moment I use `is_admin()` to include files for Administrator:

```
if (is_admin()){
    //include here
};
```

Comment: Do you want to include the files in the back-end or front-end or both? and only if current user is admin?

Comment: i want to include at the backend, and only for Administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_admin` is true when you're in the dashboard/admin area, aka `example.com/wp-admin`. It asks the question "are we in the admin area?", and is true of anybody logged in and inside the admin area. This could be a user with the role subscriber who sees only the edit profile page. This function is similar to `is_home()` or `is_single()`, and has nothing to do with the current user, only their location on the site.

`current_user_can( 'manage_options' )` is true, if the current logged in user has the capability with the name `manage_options`. Normally only administrators have these options. Note that a plugin may change this

Comment: hi thanks, but i try use `current_user_can( 'manage_options')` seems i got an error, but i still searching for it.

Comment: What error did you recieve? What's in your PHP error log? I suspect more context is needed about where this code is being ran

Comment: i will check it later, since i on travel